# How to run a simple #!/bin/sh script in alpine on Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to add a script to an alpine linux docker file, but am unable to run the script. It always results in

```
/bin/sh: /tmp/test.sh: not found 
The command '/bin/sh -c /tmp/test.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

The file has the executable flag set.

#### Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

ADD test.sh /tmp/test.sh
RUN /tmp/test.sh
```

#### test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World"
```

#### output

```
docker build --no-cache . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB 
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine 
 ---> cdf98d1859c1
Step 2/3 : ADD test.sh /tmp/test.sh
 ---> c81abfa30514 
Step 3/3 : RUN /tmp/test.sh
 ---> Running in 73b702648827 
/bin/sh: /tmp/test.sh: not found 
The command '/bin/sh -c /tmp/test.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Works for me: `---> Running in e4892dd99a6c`, `Hello World`. Succeeded 5 out of 5 tries.

Comment: works for me as well. Are you maybe running on Windows?

Comment: yes. docker for windows in ubuntu wsl /o\

Comment: then maybe add a dos2unix step just to make sure...

Comment: argh. yes that was it. thank you!

Comment: @Saskia, im facing this same problem, what was your fix?

Comment: The accepted answer.
files that i copied were not unix format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your file (test.sh) is saved in unix format if you are working on Windows.